# BigQuery Storage API: Best Practice for Using Client from Spark Pandas UDF?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-bigquery

I have a spark script that needs to make 60 api calls for every row. Currently I am using BigQuery as a data warehouse. I was wondering if there was a way I can use either the [BigQuery API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/) or [BigQuery Storage API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/storage/) to query the database from my udf? Maybe a way to perform batch queries? Would [pandas-gbq](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/pandas-gbq-migration) be a better solution? Each query that I need to make per row is a `select count(*) from dataset.table where {...}` query.

Currently I am using the big query client as shown in the code snippet below, but I am not sure if this is the best way to utilize my resources. Apologies if the code is not done properly for this use case, I am new to spark and BigQuery.

```
def clients():
    os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = '/home/hadoop/credentials.json'
    credentials, your_project_id = google.auth.default(
        scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
    )

    # Make clients.
    bqclient = bigquery.Client(
        credentials=credentials,
        project=your_project_id,
    )
    bqstorageclient = bigquery_storage_v1beta1.BigQueryStorageClient(
        credentials=credentials
    )
    return bqclient, bqstorageclient

def query_cache(query):
    bqclient, bqstorageclient = clients()

        dataframe = (
            bqclient.query(query)
                .result()
                .to_dataframe(bqstorage_client=bqstorageclient)
        )
        return dataframe['f0_'][0]

@pandas_udf(schema(), PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def calc_counts(df):
    query = "select count(*) from dataset.table where ...{some column filters}..."
    df['count'] = df.apply(query_cache, args=(query), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simpler option is to use the [spark-bigquery-connector](http://spark-bigquery-connector), which let you query BigQuery directly and get the result as a Spark dataframe. Converting this dataframe into pandas is then simple:

```
spark_df = spark.read.format('bigquery').option('table', table).load()
pandas_df = spark_df.toPandas()
```

Comment: Thank you! I think this solution would work best if I wasn't using `pandas_udf`. Currently since spark context isn't available from a `pandas_udf`, I would have to make this call from the driver, then try to access that dataframe from the udf function. I think this could lead to some memory issues If I try to do something like serialize the df as an rdd map and send/broadcast it to the udf